# Create Chart with Eloquent gives a blank chart

Tags: laravel, charts, eloquent

I'm trying to create a Chart with the eloquent result.

This is how I get the data and create the chart

```
 $result = Visit::where('created_at', '>=', now()->month)
                        ->groupBy('created_at')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get(array(
        DB::raw('Month(created_at) as date'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "views"')
    ));
//Convert the result to an Array
$resArray = $result->toArray();

//Create the Chart
 $chart = (new LarapexChart())->setTitle('Users')
        ->setSubtitle('From January To December')
        ->setType('bar')
        ->setXAxis(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep','Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])
        ->setGrid(true)
        ->setDataset([
            $resArray


        ])
        ->setStroke(1);
```

Below is the result when dd on `$resArray`

```
array:3 [▼


 0 => array:2 [▼
    "date" => 6
    "views" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "date" => 6
    "views" => 1
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "date" => 6
    "views" => 1
  ]
]
```

However, the chart is coming out blank. I'm trying to get a graph similar to the one below: [image]

This is the link the documentation I've been looking at:
[Creating a bar Chart - Larapex](https://arielmejiadev.github.io/LarapexCharts-Documentation/advanceExample.html#bar)

and the next link is for the eloquent example: [Eloquent Example](https://arielmejiadev.github.io/LarapexCharts-Documentation/eloquentExample.html)

Comment: I don't know this package, but I don't think the `date` field should be the same for each data object.

Comment: I suppose date will have to be the month? I'm not certain how I will go about making it the abbreviation of each month

Comment: You are using the keys `date` and `views` in your `$resArray` array for `setDataset`, the documentation only uses `name` and `data`,  why are you using different keys? Also I think that the `data` array corresponds to the values set in `setXAxis` so ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'] => [100, 200, 300], which would mean 100 in January, 200 in February and 300 in March. So in your case you would need an array with 12 values for each month of the year.

Comment: Maybe it's intentional but I should say it, if you want to see monthly visits I'd suggest you group by `MONTH(created_at)`, that would give you 12 rows maximum, but grouping by a date like `created_at` can give you a lot of records, grouping them in the database is much more efficient than PHP in-memory.